# Definir funciones en Common Lisp

Tags: newlisp

Estoy intentando entender como funciona Common Lisp, y mirando unos ejercicios. Encuentro que se define un árbol max-min, como sigue:

```
(max ((min (4 5))
(min (6
(max (3 4))
(max (7 9))))
(min (3 8)))))
```

Se pide definir varias funciones en Common Lisp.

En la primera se pide retornar un boleano que nos indica si el árbol es una hoja (número) o no.

He escrito algo como esto, mirando varios manuales que he encontrado en internet, pero no sé si es correcto, o no.

```
 (defun hoja-arbol (hoja)
 (numerp hoja))
```

Otras que se piden son:

- retorna un número si el árbol es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil
- retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es
  min
- retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es
  max
- retorna la lista de hijos si el árbol no es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil

Si alguien me pudiera orientar, para intentar generar las funciones que me piden, estaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

Mira esta referencia: https://sobrelisp.blogspot.com/2013/02/arboles-binarios-en-lisp.html

En la primera se pide retornar un boleano que nos indica si el árbol es una hoja (número) o no.

```
(defun es-hoja (arbol)
  "retorna un boleano que indica si el árbol es una hoja"
  (if (and (listp arbol) (not (cdr arbol)))  
      t
    nil))

(defvar arbol '(1 . ((2 . nil) . (3 . nil)))) ; => ARBOL
(es-hoja arbol) ; => NIL
(es-hoja '(4)) ; => T

retorna un número si el árbol es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil

(defun numero-es-hoja (n)
  "retorna un número si el árbol es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil"
  (if (es-hoja n)
      (car n)
    nil))

(defvar arbol '(1 . ((2 . nil) . (3 . nil)))) ;; => ARBOL
(numero-es-hoja '(4)) ;; => 4
(numero-es-hoja arbol) ;; => NIL
(numero-es-hoja '(5)) ;; => 5
```

retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es min

```
(defun es-raiz-min (arb &optional raiz)
  "retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es min"
  (if (not raiz) (setq raiz (car arb)))
  (let ((x (car arb)))
    (cond ((eq x nil)
       t)
      ((numberp x)
       (if (< x raiz)
           nil
         (es-raiz-min (cdr arb) raiz)))
      ((es-hoja x)
       (if (< (car x) raiz)
           nil
         (es-raiz-min (cdr arb) raiz)))
      (t
       (if (and (es-raiz-min (car arb) raiz) (es-raiz-min (cdr arb) raiz))
           t
         nil)))))

(setq arbol1 '(3 . ((2 . ((5 . nil) . (6 . nil))) . (1 . nil))))
(setq arbol2 '(10  .  ((2 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))
(setq arbol3 '(1 . ((2 . nil) . (3 . nil))))
(setq arbol4 '(4  .  ((32 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))

(es-raiz-min arbol1) ; => NIL
(es-raiz-min arbol2) ; => NIL
(es-raiz-min arbol3) ; => T
(es-raiz-min arbol4) ; => NIL
```

retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es max

```
(defun es-raiz-max (arb &optional raiz)
  "retorna un booleano, indica si la raíz del árbol es max"
  (if (not raiz) (setq raiz (car arb)))
  (let ((x (car arb)))
    (cond ((eq x nil)
       t)
      ((numberp x)
       (if (> x raiz)
           nil
         (es-raiz-max (cdr arb) raiz)))
      ((es-hoja x)
       (if (> (car x) raiz)
           nil
         (es-raiz-max (cdr arb) raiz)))
      (t
       (if (and (es-raiz-max (car arb) raiz) (es-raiz-max (cdr arb) raiz))
           t
         nil)))))

(setq arbol1 '(3 . ((2 . ((5 . nil) . (6 . nil))) . (1 . nil))))
(setq arbol2 '(10  .  ((2 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))
(setq arbol3 '(1 . ((2 . nil) . (3 . nil))))
(setq arbol4 '(4  .  ((32 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))
(setq arbol5 '(32  .  ((32 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))

(es-raiz-max arbol1) ; => NIL
(es-raiz-max arbol2) ; => T
(es-raiz-max arbol3) ; => NIL
(es-raiz-max arbol4) ; => NIL
(es-raiz-max arbol5) ; => T
```

retorna la lista de hijos si el árbol no es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil

```
(defun lista-hijos (arb &optional es-hijo hijos)
  "retorna la lista de hijos si el árbol no es una hoja, en otro caso retorna nil"
  (let ((x (car arb)))
    (cond ((eq x nil)
       (reverse hijos))
      ((numberp x)
       (if es-hijo
           (push x hijos))
       (lista-hijos (cdr arb) t hijos))
      ((es-hoja x)
       (if es-hijo
           (push (car x) hijos))
       (lista-hijos (cdr arb) t hijos))
      (t
       (lista-hijos (cdr arb) t (reverse (lista-hijos x t hijos)))))))

(setq arbol0 '(1))
(setq arbol1 '(1 . ((2 . ((5 . nil) . (6 . nil))) . (3 . nil))))
(setq arbol2 '(1  .  ((2 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))
(setq arbol3 '(1 . ((2 . nil) . (3 . nil))))
(setq arbol4 '(1  .  ((32 . ((4 . nil) . (5 . nil)))  .  (3 . ((6 . nil) . (7 . nil))))))

(lista-hijos arbol0) ; => NIL
(lista-hijos arbol1) ; => (2 5 6 3)
(lista-hijos arbol2) ; => (2 4 5 3 6 7)
(lista-hijos arbol3) ; => (2 3)
(lista-hijos arbol4) ; => (32 4 5 3 6 7)
```